# Can't get array to work when using self.array or any .notation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, nsmutablearray

Working on a simple project and my NSMutableArrays won’t insert and object when using a property from a class to talk to the array. So I went to a command line in Xcode  and any arrays created in main work from main then if I use .notation to talk to the array property I get the error unrecognized selector. I looked up some things an tried using a method to add objects like 
- (void)addObjectsToArray {

```
MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[list addObject:myObject];
[myObject release];

OtherClass *anotherObject = [[OtherClass alloc] init];
[list addObject:anotherObject];
[anotherObject release];
```

}

but ANY time I ask my array to addObject OR insertObject I get the unrecognized selector error (that is when ever I try using self.array or any .array from anywhere)

Here is my class .h there is no code just the property. I am trying to use newObject.array and then call insertObject on it but no go…

## import

@interface CheckArray : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;

@end

and in main I have

CheckArray *newObject = [[CheckArray alloc]init];

```
    newObject.array  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (newObject.array) {
        [newObject.array insertObject:testString atIndex:0];
    }

    NSLog(@" the new array is %@“, newObject.array);
```

the log says  2015-01-19 00:14:32.940 TestOfMutableArray[16647:518334]  new array is (
) so it exists but ....

here’s the error why does it not recognize insertObject? Thanks if you can explain.

2015-01-19 00:05:59.884 TestOfMutableArray[16608:513530] -[__NSArrayI insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001068d0
2015-01-19 00:05:59.885 TestOfMutableArray[16608:513530] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001068d0'

Answer (score 0):

`__NSArrayI` means immutable array, immutable arrays doesn't declares method for mutating its contents. Somewhere you pass to .array an `NSArray` not a `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Thank you this was the problem

Comment: @PetrosVoutsanesis You are welcome. Usually if the answer is correct, is good to mark the answer as accepted by pressing on the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `copy` to declare your property, it will turn it into immutable which is **NSArray**. Try to modify the `copy` to `strong`.

For your case, you are using a **NSMutableArray** pointer to reference a **NSArray**. That's why you can not insert.

Comment: thank you yes this does now work using strong not copy